# Setting for default column type

Tags: sql-server, datatypes

Is there a setting in SQLServer 2008 and newer for default data type of date-time columns, i.e. `datetime` or `datetime2`? Actually more like something that would tell SQLServer to use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` when creating a table/view even if the latter is requested explicitly.

---

UPDATE: Thank you everyone. With this issue I am actually on the pitching side, that is creating tables from Java application that are supposed to have `datetime` columns, but end up having `datetime2`. Thought it might be due to DBMS configuration, but, probably, it's due to intricacies of one of our frameworks. Oh well, back to digging code :)

P.S. Special thank you goes to **@srutzky** for detailed response with multiple options, but accepted **@John M**'s answer as being the most spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to automatically change a `datetime` field to a `datetime2` field if the former is specified in a table creation.

To do it manually:

`ALTER TABLE [table] MODIFY COLUMN [column] DATETIME2;`

If the issue pertains to end users, education is your best bet to make the creation of tables more uniform and compliant with using `datetime2`.

Answer (score 2):

Views do not have datatypes; they reference columns in tables that do have datatypes. You can do an explicit `CONVERT()` in a View, but just like any query, it will return the underlying type.

Now, doing what amounts to a "default" (especially inline with your request to use DATETIME2 even if someone tries to use another type) is a bit complicated and shown below. However, it is much simpler to simply "disallow" use of particular datatypes. You could create a DDL trigger to trap CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements and if someone is trying to use DATETIME, simply issue the following:

```
ROLLBACK TRAN;
RAISERROR('How many times have I said: DON''T use DATETIME! Try again with DATETIME2.', 16, 1);
RETURN;`
```

This does not require complex text parsing or any additional logic. Nor will it make you many friends.

And I am not saying that one *should* do the following, but it is possible to use a DDL Trigger to trap `CREATE TABLE` statements (which is really after the event) and then scan the DDL submitted and if anything undesired was used, issue the appropriate ALTER TABLE statement. Just keep in mind:

- the CREATE TABLE statement might include constraints and indexes which might require being dropped in order to issue the ALTER TABLE, and then obviously re-added afterwards.
- this requires better text parsing than is usually possible with straight T-SQL as there is an incredible amount of flexibility in how you can write a query that is valid syntax. So you will need to make use of SQLCLR in order to get Regular Expression functionality (i.e. Match and Replace). I am not saying that this part is an issue, just more of an FYI.

So, this isn't exactly "simple". But it is at least possible and hence why I am mentioning it here because even if this specific scenario isn't advisable, the concept is at least transferable to other scenarios.